How to expand io_uring functionality with Asio on Linux?
Asio supports async file i/o with io_uring, however there are several syscalls that can be made non-blocking that are outside of Asio's purview: mkdir, rename, setxattr, etc.

Linux 6.0+
Asio 1.30.2
C++ 20 w/ coroutines

I'm relatively new to Asio and need help figuring out:

Is it possible to tap into the io_uring instance via asio::stream_file::get_executor()? If so how can I use the io_uring_prep_* functions to setup sqes and have the backing service resume the correct coroutine?
If Asio's instance is off limits/unreachable, one can setup another ring and eventfd to integrate with asio::posix::descriptor. How does one juggle multiple suspended coroutines, resuming the right one when processing the cqe?

I have gone over the API and concepts of Asio but still am failing to fully comprehend what is needed to solve this issue. I setup a proof of concept with a second io_uring instance and eventfd however it cannot handle multiple coroutines all submitting this instance.
Sample Code
#include <asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <asio/detached.hpp>
#include <asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/write.hpp>
#include <asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <asio/stream_file.hpp>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <liburing.h>

#include <format>

using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

asio::awaitable<void> handler(tcp::socket s)
{
    asio::stream_file f(co_await asio::this_coro::executor);

    // auto sqe = ::io_uring_get_sqe(&ring);
    // ::io_uring_prep_openat(sqe, AT_FDCWD, "/etc/hostname", O_RDONLY, 0);
    // ::io_uring_submit(&ring);
    // ::io_uring_wait_cqe(&ring, &cqe);
    // f.assign(cqe->res, asio::stream_file::read_only);
    // ::io_uring_cqe_seen(&ring, cqe);
    // co_await ...

    f.open("/etc/hostname", asio::stream_file::read_only); // replace this blocking open with the io_ring stuff above
    auto msg = std::format("/etc/hostname is {} bytes\n", f.size());
    co_await asio::async_write(s, asio::buffer(msg), asio::use_awaitable);
    f.close();
    s.close();
}

asio::awaitable<void> listener()
{
    auto executor = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(executor, {tcp::v6(), 8080});
    for (;;)
    {
        auto socket = co_await acceptor.async_accept(asio::use_awaitable);
        asio::co_spawn(executor, handler(std::move(socket)), asio::detached);
    }
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx(1);
    asio::signal_set signals(ctx, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto){ ctx.stop(); });
    asio::co_spawn(ctx, listener(), asio::detached);
    ctx.run();
    return 0;
}

